# confused by numpy meshgrid output

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Using Python 2.7 with miniconda interpreter. I am confused by what means N-D coordinate in the following statements, and could anyone tell how in the below sample `xv` and `yv` are calculated, it will be great.

"Make N-D coordinate arrays for vectorized evaluations of N-D scalar/vector fields over N-D grids, given one-dimensional coordinate arrays x1, x2,..., xn."

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html

```
>>> nx, ny = (3, 2)
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 1, nx)
>>> y = np.linspace(0, 1, ny)
>>> xv, yv = meshgrid(x, y)
>>> xv
array([[ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ]])
>>> yv
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xv,yv` are simply defined as:

```
xv = np.array([x for _ in y])
yv = np.array([y for _ in x]).T
```

so that for every index pair `(i,j)`, you have

```
xv[i,j] = x[i]
yv[i,j] = y[j]
```

which is useful especially for plotting 2D maps.

Comment: Another confusion is, why in the example, it is written as `nx, ny = (3, 2)`? It sounds like a tuple (3,2), but actually I think `nx` and `ny` is a scalar integer variable (`x=3` and `y=2`)?

Comment: `nx, ny` is a tuple. All these are equivalent statements `(nx, ny) = (3, 2)`, `nx, ny = (3, 2)`, `(nx, ny) = 3, 2`, `nx, ny = 3, 2` . You are assigning a tuple to another which means `nx = 3` and `ny = 2`. This is also called 'unpacking'.

Comment: But why it is useful to plot 2D maps using `xv` and `yv`?

Comment: Play with the ij versus xy parameter.  I think it also has a sparse option.

Comment: This is just the way plot works: it takes a list of `x` coordinates, a list of `y` coordinates and the corresponding list of `z` coordinates. You could have for example `x = [0,5,4]`, `y = [2,3,1]` and (assuming you want to plot a function `f(x,y)`) `z = [f(x[0],y[0]), f(x[1],y[1]), f(x[2],y[2])] = [f(0,2), f(5,3), f(4,1)]`. This will plot those 3 points only. If you want a full 2D map, you need to create all the points on a grid, which is exactly what these `xv` and `yv` are.

Comment: Thanks Julien, so in your example `every index pair (i,j)`, `(i,j)` is the point you want to plot in the 2D plot diagram? In my example, I think the points could plot is `(0,0), (0.5, 0), (1, 0) (0, 1) (0.5, 1) and (1,1)`?

Comment: Correct. (Small vocabulary precision though: `(i,j)` would be the indices of the points, and `(xv[i,j], yv[i,j])` would be the actual points.)

Comment: Thanks Julien, wondering what is the benefit of meshgrid? In the past, my method might be naive, and I just build a 2 dimensional array to store m*n points, and each point I store as a tuple (x,y), representing its x- and y- coordinate value, and I plot f(x,y) for point (x,y).

Comment: BTW, Julien, mark your reply as answer as you already answered my original question.

Comment: Your approach seems essentially the same. The advantages of using `meshgrid` are: you don't have to rewrite code that already exists (building your 2D array of tuples) and has been extensively checked and optimised (if your profile your function, I bet you'll find it to be slower than `meshgrid`). Also it allows for easy vectorized computation of the `z` values which will also be much faster than a python loop computing all `f(x,y)` like you probably had with your approach.

Comment: I will try and adopt the new approach, thanks Julien. Have a good day.